# How to add multiple -I command line parameters in cpptasks

Tags: gcc, ant, ant-contrib

This is what I intend on reproducing using cpptasks:

```
gcc -IDir1 -IDir2 ...
```

Now using libset I am using the dir paramater to specify Dir1.How do I add Dir2 also .
Link to libset docs: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/cpptasks/antdocs/LibrarySet.html

This gives an error

```
<libset dir="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/include/linux" dir="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/include/" />
```

How do I include both the directories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide more than one libset.

```
<cpptasks:cc ... >
  <libset dir="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/include/linux" ... />
  <libset dir="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/include/" ... />
  ...
</cpptasks:cc>
```